# Time Series by group

Tags: r

I have a sample data frame x as below:

`x <- data.frame(Name = rep(c("Tom", "Mike"), each = 3), Year = rep(c(2017,2018,2019), each = 1), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))`

I would like to run a time series model to predict value in 2020 for each name (Tom and Mike here). To achieve this, first I have to transform the data frame x into a time series. However, I don't know how to to create time series by group (group = name). The code below produces weird series.

```
ts(runs_reshaped$value, frequency = 1, start = c(2017,1))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is `runs_reshaped`?

Comment: `ts` can deal with multiple time series if the data is reshaped correctly - `runs_reshaped <- reshape(x, idvar="Year", timevar="Name", direction="wide")` then `ts(runs_reshaped[-1], start=c(2017,1))`

Comment: I would look at the [tsibble](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/index.html) package. They use the concept of a `key` to identify multiple time series stored in the same table. You can then use [fable](https://fable.tidyverts.org/index.html) and [fabletools](https://fabletools.tidyverts.org/index.html) for time series analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` by 'Name' into a `list` and then create the `ts` within the `list`

```
lst1 <- split(x, x$Name)
lapply(lst1, function(u) ts(u$value, frequency = 1, start = c(u$year[1], 1)))
```

---

If we want to use this in a tidy way

```
library(fpp3)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
x %>% 
   mutate(Year = ymd(Year, truncated = 2)) %>%
   as_tsibble(key = Name, index = Year) %>% 
   model(decomp = classical_decomposition(value, type = 'additive')) # apply the models
# A mable: 2 x 2
# Key:     Name [2]
#  Name           decomp
#  <chr>         <model>
#1 Mike  <DECOMPOSITION>
#2 Tom   <DECOMPOSITION>
```